# Field not showing in TFS 2017 WebLayout

Tags: tfs

I have enabled the new work item form in TFS 2017 after upgrading from TFS 2015, but have found that there are some fields that aren't showing in the new work item form, even though I can see the field declared in the WebLayout section when editing the work item type XML. Is there a condition which hides fields in WebLayout?

The field I am trying to get appear is the `Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork` field. I have the following inside the WebLayout:

```
<WebLayout>
    <!- Snipped some other groups which show -->
    <Group Label="Timescales">
       <!-- Snipped Some other fields which show -->
       <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" Type="FieldControl" Label="Remaining Work" />
    </Group>
</WebLayout>
```

I also had the same issue with a custom String field, but I no longer needed the field so I removed it anyway.

Comment: Is it a custom field? Can you give its name? What you need to check is if there are any rules on the field and in the state transitions that would set it to readonly or hide it in some fashion.

Comment: It's the built in Remaining Work field. There isn't anything which hides it. If I switch from.the new work item form back to the pre-2017 form, it shows fine. It is only hidden in the new work item form introduced in 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I found was that when I changed between 2 particular statuses, the transition was clearing the Remaining Work field value. I'm guessing that the WebLayout doesn't display invalid fields, as a blank string is not a valid Double field, which Remaining Work is defined as

Answer (score 1):

The field is not shown and declared  in Web Layout, you need to double check if the field is hidden or have an invalid value of the field.

In your case, you can edit the work item type to add the **REQUIRED** role from `Remaining Work field` when change particular States (such as from Done to In Progress). Please follow the below steps:

1. Open your work item type using TFS Power Tools in (Process Editor).
2. Under **Workflow** tab, find the **Transition** which from Done to
   In Progress, then double click on this Transition.
3. In **Workflow Transition** dialog, under Fields tab, add the Remaining
   Work field, then click OK button and save your work item type.

As a workaround, when you change the statuses, even though the transition was clearing the Reamining Work filed, still need to enter the value for the field.

Comment: It is declared in the WebLayout, but did find that a transition emptied the remaining work, which his the field in the new form. I have changed the transition to change the value to 0 as there wasn't really a reason to clear the field. Is there a reason why it hides invalid fields? Doesn't seem user-friendly to me as there is no feedback as to why it's not showing

Comment: @StevenBrookes  Since Work items have received a face lift to provide a fresher, more modern experience to tracking work. The deal with the legacy work items sometimes leads to these problems when you switch to the new experience . It's not documented directly. We're always interested in how to improve the experience. What do you like or don't like about the new form layout and experience? 
Send your suggestions via UserVoice.Details about New work item tracking experience, refer https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/new-work-item-experience#switch-to-the-new-experience